# Why do nearly all php-related e-commerce websites use object-oriented programming as a basic foundation?

Tags: php, oop, e-commerce

I was just looking through many books about php e-commerce websites (like [Beginning PHP and MySQL E-Commerce](http://www.apress.com/9781590598641)) and I realised that so many use object-oriented programming as a basic foundation. I thought about it, and I realised it is perfectly possible to replicate those e-commerce websites without using object-oriented programming, so why do they all go for OOP?

Thanks,

Lucas

Comment: I don't think this is specific to e-commerce - OOP is far easier to maintain than procedural code along with all the other OO benefits (modularity, extensibility, reusability)

Comment: yes, but a similar framework can be established without using OOP...

Comment: like just putting functions in `func.inc.php`, putting mysql connection code in `mysql.connect.php`, etc. would still be good code organizing.

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, personally I go for OOP.

Comment: @think123 The bottom line is you can write it any way you like - but if you're developing something that will be used or maintained by other developers, they'll thank you for making good design decisions now.

Comment: @think123 It's not just about organizing the code, it's about organizing the entire logical structure of the application (which, ideally, should be done before any line of code is written). For complex projects the object paradigm makes it easier both for current and future developers of the project.

Comment: I would say modern e-commerce solutions go with the modern paradigms. There are many function-oriented giants like wordpress that are hard to customize. I am sure they would love to upgrade to OOP as well, but they can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question actually boils down to "Why do most people use OOP?".

The short answer is because we can ;-)
The longer answer is: A good program in a non OOP language still tries to organize itself into sensible chunks that are pretty similar to objects. For example, a C library that takes an opaque data structure as the first parameter of each method.  OOP languages have just made it easier to do. (i.e. you don't need that opaque data, because "this" does the same job.

If you are writing in a language that has all the bells an whistles to organize you code into smaller pieces, you'll find it much easier to maintain than writing the whole app in one giant main() [I won't go into the whole why OOP is better]

Any OOP program can be written as non OO - early C++ compilers just converted C++ into C and compiled that - but why would you?